# Chrome occasionally renders my HTML/CSS differently

Tags: html, css

I just started learning HTML/CSS and am trying to make a personal site from scratch (no CSS tools)

When I tested my site in Firefox and IE last night it looked nice and clean as seen
[image: http://i.imgur.com/vQd57rk.png]

When I tested my site in Chrome my links got moved around: 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/DjaziKg.png]

Does anybody know what happened here?
This is my markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home | Some Website!</title>
        <style>
            * {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

            body {
                width: 960px;
                font-size: small;
                font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                line-height: 1.6em;
                background-color: #FFFFF0;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

            #header {
                border-style: solid;
            }
            #header img {
                margin: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
            }

            #header ul {
                list-style-type: none;
                display: inline;
                margin: 25px 30px 0px 0px;
                float: right;
                font-size: x-large;
            }

            #header ul li {
                display: inline;
                margin: 0 30px;
            }

            #header li a:link {
                color: #FF00FF;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            #header li a:hover {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YbAx7y1.png" alt="Temp Logo!">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="resume.html">R&eacute;sum&eacute;</a></li>
                <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: no problem for me too! it looks like as in Firefox image.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dZJEr/ I didn't have a problem either.

Comment: I ran in actual chrome as a file and it does show incorrectly.

Comment: You should try using [CSS reset stylesheets](http://www.cssreset.com/) to ensure all the CSS modifications you do will end up giving the same result on any browser.

Comment: Looks fine to me in Chrome v.28

Comment: Debugging tip: stuff like this happens when you float stuff. Easy poor-man's way to debug floats is to give the relevant boxes fugly background colours. Give #header #f00 for example and #header ul #00f;

Comment: Can you reproduce this consistently? I tried jsfiddle and a local html file and could not reproduce. Maybe your version of chrome is old like andi mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Change `#header ul` css definition from`display: inline;` to `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: Oh good idea! Thanks for the tip, I'm still new to this thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Every browser interprets things differently. You should be more specific than `body { font-size: small }`. I recommend using a px value unless you really intend to leave it up to the browser.